# Python/Regex: How to slice string by regex pattern while keeping the pattern in the matches as well?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that contains sentences in the form:

> "Ms Smith to talk to her colleague Ms Smith to create new events for
>   the team. team Leader's assistant to organise morning stand-up session. to drive around the city."

- The sentences may or may not not have punctuation or correct casing.
- There could be noise in the text as well (extra characters, words).
- I want to slice by the following structures:

  - "Miss/Ms/Mr/Mrs  to"
  - "Miss/Ms/Mr/Mrs 's  to"
  - "Team Leader to"
  - "Team Leader's  to"
  - ". To"

I would like to slice this into the list:

```
["Ms Smith to talk to her colleague",
"Ms Smith to create new events for the team.",
"team Leader's assistant to organise morning stand-up session.",
"to drive around the city."]
```

My current solution works, but is very un-pythonic, I'm sure there are ways to avoid a while loop:

```
def slice(text):
    parts = []
    rule = "(^.+?)(?:(?:miss [a-z]+|ms [a-z]+|mrs [a-z]+|mr [a-z]+|team leader)(?:'s [a-z ]+?)?|\.) to.+?$"
    while True:
        try:
            part = re.findall(rule, text)[0]
            parts.append(part)
            # Remove part from text for next iteration
            text = text[len(part):]
        except IndexError:
            # findall returned empty list
            break
    # Add the remainder
    parts.append(text)
    return parts
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you also want to slice if the sentence ends i.e. with a full stop?

Comment: @RahulP No, there might be extra full stops in the text (it's OCRd)

Comment: For this non-trivial rules you could use `re.VERBOSE` that'll allow you to add comments and split the big rule by short self-explained rule chunks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do all of what you want to do with just `findall` and capturing subgroups. Is this output what you had in mind?

```
import re

s = "Ms Smith to talk to her colleague Ms Smith to create new events for the team. " +\
    "team Leader's assistant to organise morning stand-up session. to drive around the city."

roles = "Miss|Ms|Mr|Mrs|team leader"
matches = re.findall(f"""
    (
        \ ?
        (
            (?:{roles})?      # Read the role
            (?:[\w\'\-\ ]*?)  # and name to group(1) aka "identity"
        )
        to
        ([\w\'\-\ ]+?)  # Read the other words to group(2) aka "task"
        (?={roles}|\.)  # until next role or dot
        [\.\ ]?
    )
    """,
    s,
    flags=re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE,
)

print("Full matches:")
for m in matches:
    print(" *", m[0].strip())


print("\nSplit by identity and task:")
for full, identity, task in matches:
    print(f" * Identity: '{identity}', task: '{task.strip()}, full match: '{full.strip()}'")
```

Output:

> Full matches:
>    * Ms Smith to talk to her colleague
>    * Ms Smith to create new events for the team.
>    * team Leader's assistant to organise morning stand-up session.
>    * to drive around the city.
>
> Split by identity and task:
>    * Identity: 'Ms Smith ', task: 'talk to her colleague, full match: 'Ms Smith to talk to her colleague'
>    * Identity: 'Ms Smith ', task: 'create new events for the team, full match: 'Ms Smith to create new events for the team.'
>    * Identity: 'team Leader's assistant ', task: 'organise morning stand-up session,
>    full match: 'team Leader's assistant to organise morning stand-up
>    session.'
>   * Identity: '', task: 'drive around the city, full match:
>   'to drive around the city.'

Comment: Would you like my readability suggestion:

```python
matches = re.findall(f"""
    (
        \ ?
        (
            (?:{roles})?  # Read the role name to group(1) aka "identity"
            (?:[\w\'\-\ ]*?)
        )
        to
        ([\w\'\-\ ]+?)  # Read the words to group(2) aka "task"
        (?={roles}|\.)  # Until next role starts or dot not founded.
        [\.\ ]?
    )
    """,
    s,
    flags=re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE,
)
```